# The view was not found when using a string ID

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I have this method in my `HomeController`,it worked fine when going to `support/home/chat` but if i go to `/support/home/chat?id=4` it will give the error:

> **InvalidOperationException: The view '4' was not found**

```
 [Area("Support")]
    public IActionResult Chat(string? ID)
    {
       

        return View(ID);
    }
```

and this is my routing in startup

```
  app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapAreaControllerRoute(
                    name: "Support",
                    areaName: "Support",
                    pattern: "Support/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

            });
```

Comment: If ID is not null then you are trying to load a view named "4" (or whatever value has ID). Are you trying to pass the ID as parameter to your View named Chat?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Controller.View has many overloads (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.controller.view?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2)

let's focus on

- View(string path)
- View(object model)

the first one is used when you want to use a view with a given path and no model, the second one is used when you want to use the default view with a model.
In your case you want to use the second one, but your model is of type string and so you are actually using the first one.

all you have to do is:

```
 return View((object)ID);
```